# Node/Browser Javascript Library with Server Side Events

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I am building a shared node/browser javascript library. I want to use EventStream, relying on the browser built in version for the browser, and if its node use this library: https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/eventsource-node

How do I conditionally require the node library if I'm in a node environment, and use the built in browser version if I'm in the browser?

Comment: Are you using something like browserify to create your browser package? If so, you can browserify-shim any `var EventSource = require("eventsource")` to point to the browser's EventSource implementation instead.

Comment: Eventsource isn't compatible with all browsers. It might be easier to just use Websockets/socket.io to communicate between server and browser.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Eventsource is another name for Server-Sent Events. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: @dylanweber I know. And the spec that the `eventsource` nodejs package mirrors is called [EventSource](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/).